# How to put React code into a separate file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to React and having trouble placing React code into separate files (i.e. moving the React code out of my main html file). Here is a simple example. The code below works fine. I get the correct "Hello, World!" output.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root') );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I try to split this into 2 files, "Hello, world!" does not display at all. That code is below:

```js
ReactDOM.render( <
  h1 > Hello, world! < /h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

  <!-- Don't use this in production: -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/babel" src="component2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Why does this not work when I split it into 2 files?

Comment: Can you open your browser's dev tools and check the console for errors? The simplest explanation would be that the browser can't locate component2.js.

Comment: `type="text/babel"` is not a valid MIME type.

Comment: @SydneyY's advice worked here. When I inspected in the browser and then looked in the console I got the following error:

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct. Remove the `type="text/babel"` from the html file

Then convert your JSX into plain using by keeping it in an src folder and running the command
`npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod`

which will create a file *component2.js*

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
  'h1',
  null,
  'Hello, world!'
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

From *src/component2.js*, which is

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```js
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
  'h1',
  null,
  'Hello, world!'
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
 <script src="component2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can find the documentation about the same in https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: Just an additional note: `type="text/babel"` isn't necessarily wrong, it's the way babel standalone works: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone.  It's meant to transpile in-place, I believe, as an alternative to node modules.

Answer (score 0):

@SydneyY's advice I think worked here. When I inspected in the browser and then looked in the console I got errors like this:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at component2.js from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I was able to solve this issue by setting up a local development environment using create-react-app and then importing component2.js through the index.js file that create-react-app sets up.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you got that sorted out. Create-react-app is a nice-to-have but not strictly necessary; you could also have created a basic Express server to serve your static files.  If the same server serves index.html as serves component2.js, you're golden, no imports required.

Answer (score -1):

Your .js file is not having access to ReactDOM and you will also need to add

> type="text/babel"

as script attribute.